# How to draw a bar chart form data base, only series

Tags: charts, draw

I've been strugling for weeks trying desperatly to get a simple bar-chart out of a MySQL database.
The data base keeps the results of a simple test with : date, first name, last name, and the number of points for each answer to the 20 questions.

The problem is that I can't get a chart out one single row with 20 series (the results of one candidate), I get only one bar.

When I use :

```
   result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  xxxx");
```

I get a chart with the results of all candidates to the first question (1  bar for each).

With the following code :

```
   result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  xxxx WHERE id=1");
```

I obtain one and only bar.

Comment: What language are you using? How do you set the data from the database into the chart? Gonna need a lot more details...